# XOR Encryption code produces wrong results

Tags: c, encryption, xor

In the code blocks given below I am supposed to obtain an output like this:

- Expected ciphertext: `"'\r\u0006R\u0014\u0001\u001a\u0006\bR\a\u0006\u001c\u0012\rR\u0003\u001b\vE\t\a\b\u0004\0E\f\u0004\0\u0006S\u0011\v\u0017E\u0018\u0012\u001f\u001aR\u0001\u001b\u0014K"`
- Plain text: `"The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog."`
- Secret: `"secret"`
- My Output: `24 R`

Original code address: https://www.programmingalgorithms.com/algorithm/xor-encryption/c/

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
/***********************************************/

char *XORCipher(char *data, char *key, int dataLen, int keyLen) {
  char *output = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * dataLen);

  for (int i = 0; i < dataLen; ++i) {
    output[i] = data[i] ^ key[i % keyLen];
  }

  return output;
}

int main(void) {

  char *text = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.";
  char *key = "secret";
  int dataLen = strlen((char *)text);
  int keyLen = strlen((char *)key);

  char *cipherText = XORCipher(text, key, dataLen, keyLen);

  printf("%ld\n", strlen(cipherText));

  char *plainText = XORCipher(cipherText, key, dataLen, keyLen);
  printf("%s\n", cipherText);
  printf("%s\n", plainText);
}
```

Comment: You won't be able to use `%s` with anything that has an embedded zero (null) character (i.e. where `data[i] == key[i % keyLen]` since xoring a value with itself results in a zero). Instead of trying to use `%s` with the ciphered data, print out the byte values.

Comment: On an unrelated not, if you have a variable of a specific type, there's no need to cast it to the exact same type. For example the `(char*)cipherText` cast.

Comment: Also, every call to `malloc` (or other standard C allocation function) should be matched by a call to `free`.

Comment: I did not get a meaningful response from binary data, I did what you advised.

Comment: The website you've got this code from is not giving you high-quality C. There's several defects in their code -- `sizeof(char)`, missing consts, needless casts, casting the value returned from `malloc`, use of `int` instead of `size_t`. Even the "expected ciphertext" is wrong, as the ciphertext is not unicode (it's bytes). Maybe none of things is an absolute mistake, it's just that it's not good C as is practiced by experienced C-programmers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So as said, there's nothing really wrong about your encryption code, you just can't print all of those bytes.

Here's a slight rework that

- moves the allocation outside the XORCipher function (so the caller is responsible for memory management)
- adds an utility function to print byte values as well as the ASCII text

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

static void XORCipher(const char *data, const char *key, char *dest, int dataLen, int keyLen) {
  for (int i = 0; i < dataLen; ++i) {
    dest[i] = data[i] ^ key[i % keyLen];
  }
}

static void print_hex(const char *header, const unsigned char *data, int length) {
    int i = 0;
    while(i < length) {
        char asc_line[17] = {0};
        printf("%s(%04x): ", header, i);
        for(int j = 0; j < 16; i++, j++) {
            if(i < length) {
                printf("%02x ", data[i]);
                asc_line[j] = (data[i] >= 32 && data[i] <= 127 ? data[i] : '.');
            } else {
                printf("   ");
            }
        }
        printf("| %-16s |\n", asc_line);
    }
    printf("%s\n----\n", data);
}

int main(void) {

  char *text = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.";
  char *key = "secret";
  int dataLen = strlen((char *)text);
  int keyLen = strlen((char *)key);
  char *output = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * dataLen);
  print_hex("Original text", text, dataLen);
  XORCipher(text, key, output, dataLen, keyLen);
  print_hex("Ciphered text", output, dataLen);
  XORCipher(output, key, output, dataLen, keyLen);
  print_hex("Deciphered text", output, dataLen);
}
```

[The output is](https://godbolt.org/z/r35dnfhb1)

```
Original text(0000): 54 68 65 20 71 75 69 63 6b 20 62 72 6f 77 6e 20 | The quick brown  |
Original text(0010): 66 6f 78 20 6a 75 6d 70 73 20 6f 76 65 72 20 74 | fox jumps over t |
Original text(0020): 68 65 20 6c 61 7a 79 20 64 6f 67 2e             | he lazy dog.     |
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
----
Ciphered text(0000): 27 0d 06 52 14 01 1a 06 08 52 07 06 1c 12 0d 52 | '..R.....R.....R |
Ciphered text(0010): 03 1b 0b 45 09 07 08 04 00 45 0c 04 00 06 53 11 | ...E.....E....S. |
Ciphered text(0020): 0b 17 45 18 12 1f 1a 52 01 1b 14 4b             | ..E....R...K     |
'
RR
RE  
----
Deciphered text(0000): 54 68 65 20 71 75 69 63 6b 20 62 72 6f 77 6e 20 | The quick brown  |
Deciphered text(0010): 66 6f 78 20 6a 75 6d 70 73 20 6f 76 65 72 20 74 | fox jumps over t |
Deciphered text(0020): 68 65 20 6c 61 7a 79 20 64 6f 67 2e             | he lazy dog.     |
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
----
```

(Note I'm deciphering the `output` back into `output` – that's fine in this instance since we know the cipher function works byte by byte.)

Comment: Good answer, but you assume `char` is unsigned in `print_hex`.

Comment: @PaulHankin Good catch. Fixed `print_hex`'s signature to that effect.

Comment: Thank you all for your contributions, according to your feedback I rewrite and obtained the matching results with you. Thanks.